# Application name appears broken in GNOME title bar

Tags: gtk, pygobject, gtk4

I am trying to write applications with PyGObject. I have set the app name using GLib but it seems to be broken. There is no problem with other system programs that use Turkish characters in their titles.

```
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '4.0')
gi.require_version('Adw', '1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Adw, GLib


class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_default_size(300, 400)
        self.set_title("Merhaba dünya!")
        GLib.set_application_name("Merhaba Dünya!")
        GLib.set_prgname('Merhaba Dünya!')

        self.main_box = Gtk.Box(
            orientation = Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL
        )
        self.set_child(self.main_box)

        self.lbl_hello = Gtk.Label(
            label = "Merhaba dünya"
        )
        self.main_box.append(self.lbl_hello)

        self.btn_hello = Gtk.Button(
            label = "Bana tıkla"
        )
        self.btn_hello.connect(
            "clicked",
            self.btn_hello_clicked
        )
        self.main_box.append(self.btn_hello)
    def btn_hello_clicked(self, button):
        print("Merhaba dünya!")

class MyApp(Adw.Application):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.connect('activate', self.on_activate)

    def on_activate(self, app):
        self.win = MainWindow(application=app)
        self.win.present()

app = MyApp(application_id="net.teteos.example")
app.run(sys.argv)
```

[image: broken title]